# Type Classes in Haskell - how can I make GHC make a choice of types, when the type chosen doesn't matter?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

This is a question about the use of type classes in Haskell.

I get an error (below) when trying to compile the code (below and at
https://github.com/chrisdew/haskell-sandbox/blob/master/not_working_but_clean.hs
).

As someone just learning Haskell, I have tried following GHC's advice,
but I think the cause is different.

I believe the problem is that either of the types 'IO String' or plain
'String' could be the type of 'lhello ->> lbracket', but GHC doesn't
know which.

The problem is that it doesn't matter, either type would work fine.

I have posted a working version of the code at
https://github.com/chrisdew/haskell-sandbox/blob/master/working_but_ugly.hs
.  This replaces one of the ->> operators with a new (non type class)
operator '->>>' which forces 'lhello ->> lbracket' to be of type 'IO
String'.

- Is my analysis correct?  Or is there something else going on here?
- Is there any way of informing GHC what the type of 'lhello ->>
  lbracket' doen't matter and that is should just chose either of the
  two possibilities.  Or perhaps theres a LANGUAGE option which will let
  me specify that 'lastest declared matching instance of the class wins'
  if anything is undecided.

Thanks,

Chris.

Error:

```
chris@chris-linux-desktop:~/nonworkspace/haskell-sandbox$ ghc
not_working_but_clean.hs

not_working_but_clean.hs:40:16:

   No instance for (Stream (IO String) (IO String) (IO String) d)
     arising from a use of '->>' at not_working_but_clean.hs:40:16-34
   Possible fix:
     add an instance declaration for
     (Stream (IO String) (IO String) (IO String) d)
   In the first argument of '(->>)', namely 'lhello ->> lbracket'
   In the second argument of '($)', namely
       'lhello ->> lbracket ->> putStrLn'
   In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
         forkIO $ lhello ->> lbracket ->> putStrLn

not_working_but_clean.hs:40:16:
   No instance for (Stream d String (IO ()) (IO ()))
     arising from a use of `->>' at not_working_but_clean.hs:40:16-47
   Possible fix:
     add an instance declaration for (Stream d String (IO ()) (IO ()))
   In the second argument of `($)', namely
       `lhello ->> lbracket ->> putStrLn'
   In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
         forkIO $ lhello ->> lbracket ->> putStrLn
   In the expression:
       do { forkIO $ (bracket $ hello) ->> putStrLn;
            forkIO $ lhello ->> lbracket ->> putStrLn;
        forkIO $ bracket hello ->> putStrLn;
            forkIO $ lbracket lhello ->> putStrLn;
          .... }
```

not_working_but_clean.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances,
TypeSynonymInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC #-}

module Main (
main
)
where

import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, MVar, newEmptyMVar, putMVar,
takeMVar, ThreadId, threadDelay)
import Control.Monad (forever, liftM)

class Stream a b c d where
   (->>) :: a -> (b -> c) -> d

instance Stream (IO d) d (IO c) (IO c) where
   f ->> g = f >>= g

instance Stream d d (IO c) (IO c) where
   f ->> g = g f

instance Stream d d c c where
   x ->> y = y $ x

-- This simply wraps a string in brackets.
bracket :: String -> String
bracket x = "(" ++ x ++ ")"

lbracket :: IO String -> IO String
lbracket x = liftM bracket x

hello :: String
hello = "Hello World!"

lhello :: IO String
lhello = do return hello

main :: IO ()
main = do
      forkIO $ (bracket $ hello) ->> putStrLn
      forkIO $ lhello ->> lbracket ->> putStrLn
      forkIO $ bracket hello ->> putStrLn
      forkIO $ lbracket lhello ->> putStrLn
      threadDelay 10000000 -- Sleep for at least 10 seconds before exiting.
```

working_but_ugly.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances,
TypeSynonymInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC #-}

module Main (
main
)
where

import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, MVar, newEmptyMVar, putMVar,
takeMVar, ThreadId, threadDelay)
import Control.Monad (forever, liftM)

class Stream a b c d where
   (->>) :: a -> (b -> c) -> d

instance Stream (IO d) d (IO c) (IO c) where
   f ->> g = f >>= g

instance Stream d d (IO c) (IO c) where
   f ->> g = g f

instance Stream d d c c where
   x ->> y = y $ x

x ->>> y = y $ x

-- This simply wraps a string in brackets.
bracket :: String -> String
bracket x = "(" ++ x ++ ")"

lbracket :: IO String -> IO String
lbracket x = liftM bracket x

hello :: String
hello = "Hello World!"

lhello :: IO String
lhello = do return hello

main :: IO ()
main = do
      forkIO $ (bracket $ hello) ->> putStrLn
      forkIO $ lhello ->>> lbracket ->> putStrLn
      forkIO $ bracket hello ->> putStrLn
      forkIO $ lbracket lhello ->> putStrLn
      threadDelay 10000000 -- Sleep for at least 10 seconds before exiting.
```

Comment: I feel frightened when I see type classes with multiple totally independent type arguments. From a brief overlook I'd say that c depends on b and d is always the same as c. Perhaps give it a try with appropriate functional dependencies and one type less, maybe things will get easier then. EDIT: also b seems to depend on a

Comment: @lngo a and b have almost the same type, they are constrained to: a == b || IO a == b || a == IO b.  c and d have the same constraint.  I don't know how to form this constraint in Haskell.

Comment: Multiparameter type classes without functional dependencies is just asking for trouble, as you noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to make GHC flip a coin and pick one.

All of your instances have type 'c' the same as type 'd', so you could probably omit type 'd' and reuse type 'c' in defining Stream.

```
instance Stream d d (IO c) (IO c) where
   f ->> g = g f

instance Stream d d c c where
   x ->> y = y $ x
```

The above are the same.  "g f" and "y $ x" are the same.  So why two different instances??

Comment: Yes, those two instances are an oversight.  The second is sufficient.